# Joining tables using FLWOR

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

I have a question regarding FLWOR joins. Here's an overview of how my XMLs look like.

```
<user>
  <user-id>...</user-id>
  <username>...</username>
  <password>...</password>
  <!-- By schema file, there could be unbounded role-ids -->
  <role-id>...</role-id>
  <role-id>...</role-id>
  <role-id>...</role-id>
</user>

<role>
  <role-id>...</role-id>
  <name>...</name>
  <!-- By schema file, there could be unbounded permission-ids -->
  <permission-id>...</permission-id>
  <permission-id>...</permission-id>
  <permission-id>...</permission-id>
</role>

<permission>
  <permission-id>...</permission-id>
  <resource-id>...</resource-id>
  <operation-id>...</operation-id>
</permission>
```

I have a FLWOR expression, query, which should return a sequence of permissions for a given user. It should be simple enough, however I can't figure out why I'm getting an empty ResourceSet every time run the query.

```
for $i in collection("data/rbac/users")/user[user-id="..."]/role-id
for $j in collection("data/rbac/roles")/roles/role
for $k in collection("data/rbac/permissions")/permission
where $i = $j/role-id and exists($j/permission-id[. = $k/permission-id])
return $k
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.
Thanks,

Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell since the structure of the source XML data isn't completely clear. But there seems to be a small inconsistency - the second line of your XQuery assumes a node named `roles` inside your collection `data/rbac/roles`. Maybe the second line should look like

> `for $j in collection("data/rbac/roles")/role`

? Just guessing...

Comment: I forgot to mention. There is a <roles>...</roles> wraper around <role>..</role> elements, therefore to access role, I have to access the roles, first. Anyways, thanks for effort!

Answer (score 1):

Your XQuery does not seem to match the data you provide. For example `role-id` is not a child of `user`, and also there does not seem to be a `roles` element. This query given the provided XML will likely return an empty resource set.